# Android setOnTouchListener for Gridview works only for the first row

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener

I'm developing a custom button, when i touch an item of gridview the content have to change the background and move the imageview and text, to simulate the button pressed, and when the button is released all elements have to restore they original state. Using setOnTouchListener this specs works, but for the first row, when i click another row the effect is applied on the first row. This is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package sumare.sumare;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView menu;
    String[] botoes={
            "Avisos",
            "Calendario",
            "Notas",
            "Grade",
            "Rematricula",
            "Financeiro",
            "Serviços",
            "Biblioteca"
    };


   int[] imagens = {
           R.drawable.ic_announcement_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_event_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_assignment_turned_in_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_school_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_border_color_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_attach_money_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_build_white_48dp,
           R.drawable.ic_local_library_white_48dp
   };

    private class Item {
        final String texto;
        final int imagem;
        final int id;

        Item(int Id,String Texto, int Imagem) {
            this.id = Id;
            this.texto = Texto;
            this.imagem = Imagem;

        }
    }

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Faculdade Sumaré");
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.titlecolor));

        menu = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdMenu);
        menu.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(this));
        menu.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                final ImageView imgatual = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
                final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.Botao);
                final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imgatual.getLayoutParams();

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    param.topMargin = 6;
                    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.botao_pressionado));
                    imgatual.setLayoutParams(param);

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    param.topMargin = 0;
                    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.botao_normal));
                    imgatual.setLayoutParams(param);
                }


                return true;
            }
        });


        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MenuAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            int i=0;

            for (String des : botoes) {
                items.add(new Item(i,des,imagens[i]));
                i++;
            };


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return items.get(i).id;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View v = view;
            ImageView imagem;
            TextView Texto;

            if (v == null) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.botao, viewGroup, false);
                v.setTag(R.id.txtBotao, v.findViewById(R.id.txtBotao));
                v.setTag(R.id.imgButton, v.findViewById(R.id.imgButton));
            }

            imagem = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.imgButton);
            Texto = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.txtBotao);

            Item item = (Item) getItem(i);

            //picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            imagem.setImageResource(item.imagem);
            Texto.setText(item.texto);

            return v;
        }



    }
}
```

Any suggestion of how do this with another way, or how do this works?